# iOS Google sign in failed

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I have done anything on [Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift), but it crashed when I call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`.

#### Code:

At AppDelegate:

```
func configGoogleServer() {
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError as Optional)")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}
```

At some viewController:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

And I have configured URL scheme like `com.googleusercontent.apps.598xxx...xxx`.

### Crash screenshot:

[image]

And there was nothing showing on Debug Area... :(

Comment: How did you install the sdk?

Comment: You can find example code by google [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/signin/SignInExampleSwift)

Comment: Add the exact error thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the delegate inside the `AppDelegate.swift`, it's not true, you AppDelegate should be like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // .. something else

        // GOOGLE
        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        // No delegate here

        return true
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                 annotation: annotation)
    }

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
            if let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String {
                let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
                return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                         sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                         annotation: annotation)
            }

            return true
        }
```

And then put the SignIn Delegate inside YourViewController which signing-in action happens:ư

```
    class YourViewController: UIViewController  {
         // something else....

         func doSignIn() {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = YOUR_GOOGLE_SCOPES

                if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
                } else {
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
                }

          }
    }

extension YourViewController: GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            self.showMessage("Authentication Error", type: .error)
            self.service.authorizer = nil
        } else {
            self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
            // PUT YOUR METHOD AFTER SIGNED-IN HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I should set ViewController to delegate, and it fixed now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add below code into YourViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,GIDSignInUIDelegate {

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
      }
}
```

you forget implement a delegate:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return
    }
   else{
//handle response
}
  }
```